# MacOS views rendering same font differently

Tags: cocoa, fonts, nstextfield, appkit, nspopupbuttoncell

I did a mockup project that contains solely three views:

- NSTextField
- NSPopUpButton
- NSDatePicker

All of them with the same font `System - Regular, 13`.

However, as you can notice by the attached image, the fonts are different on each of the views.

Is this an expected behaviour? How to make the fonts look consistent across all these different views?

[image: Example]

Comment: The date picker is probably using the mono-spaced digits font, as obtained via `+[NSFont monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize:weight:]`. Since El Capitan, the default is proportionally-spaced digits, which is what the other two are presumably using. Not sure about the other differences.

Comment: Can you post that sample code online?